# c++ - How to use `this` to access member variables in an array of classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, static

Given a C++ class with assorted member data values and a static int counter, I'd like to have a `clear()` function that can walk all the elements of an array of these class objects clearing their data members.

So, for example, a class that looks like this and holds a chip's version information (yes, I know I probably need more setters and getters):

```
class  __STA_version_t
{  
   public:
      __STA_version_t() { count++; };
      ~__STA_version_t() {};
      void     setVerString( char* x )    { strncpy( verString, x, sizeof(verString)); verString[sizeof(verString)-1] = 0
      void     clearVerString()           { memset( verString, 0x0, sizeof(verString) ); }
      char*    getVerString()             { return verString; }    
      bool     hasVersion()               { return verString[0]; }      
      void     clear()
      { 
         for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
         {
           // what goes here?
         }
      }

   private:
      static int    count;                // how many of these objects exist, need to know for clear().

      char          verString[20];        // station version as a string
      UINT8         major_ver;            // major version identifier (3 bits)
      UINT8         minor_ver;            // minor version identifier (6 bits)
      UINT8         revision;             // revision identifier (4 bits)
      UINT8         chip_ident;           // target chip identifier (3 bits)
};
```

Elsewhere initialize `count` thusly:

```
__STA_version_t::count = 0;
```

Now, create an array of there objects:

```
__STA_version_t      versions[10];
```

First, just checking, count should equal 10 after this instantiation, right?

In the `clear()` function, I'd like to say something like:

```
this[i]->clearVerString();
this[j]->revision = 0;
// etc.
```

to clear each data member of each element of the array.

Can this be made to work?  How?

Comment: What's wrong with just using std::vector<__STA_version_t>?

Comment: In addition a static count rarely will work the way you want it to if your code is not a toy program.  You have temporaries, copying, etc. happening during the running of the program, and that "count" member may have a value you didn't expect it to have.

Comment: Have to look into this.  Pointers?  And, no, it was aimed at a commercial use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the class can't see outside its boundaries and the container is outside of the class' boundary.

You should use a standard container.  Make the `clear` method clear data members in the class.

The standard containers have methods for determining the number of items.

See `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::map`, etc.

Comment: Ditto my comment to @Ozraptor

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not very "object oriented" IMO. I would argue that the class `clear()` member function you are trying to implement here should only clear the data of the instantiated object on which it is invoked. What you are trying to do is clear the data in *all* instantiations of your class, via calling `clear()` on any/one of them only?

A better approach here would be to store your objects in a `std::vector<__STA_version_t>`, and then write a static function on your class that either takes the vector as a parameter (ideally), or can access it globally somehow, called maybe `clearAll()`. Have that function iterate through the vector and call `clear()` on each object in the vector. The `clear()` function would then simply call `clearVerString()` etc on itself - eg: 
`this->clearVerString();`
`this->revision = 0;` and so on (noting that you don't actually need to use the `this` pointer if you don't want to).

Comment: You are quite right.  The more I thought about this last night the more wrong it got in my head.  I suspect I  can come up with a much better design this morning.